# Loading jcarousel dynamically with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, dynamic, loading, jcarousel, modernizr

as a front-end developer I try to keep all javascript part to my end as I have very bad experience with some back-end guys. So I use to load all the javascript dependencies according to needs based on existence of css "ID"s in a particular page. And to do that I use Modernizr, in that way backend developer need not to worry about in which page they need to load specific javascript files and which are not.

Recently, I tried to load jQuery Carousel, loading is successful,  got the bindings as it shows in firebug. But it does not work.

link - `http://59.160.209.51/websites/eamonreganirishart/code/ - Please copy/paste this link to the browser`

## and the Modernizr code

> Modernizr.addTest("car_0", $("#mycarousel").length > 0);
>    Modernizr.load({
>         test:Modernizr.car_0,
>           yep:[temp_path+"/css/skins/tango/skin.css", temp_path+"/js/libraries/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"],
>           callback: function(){
>               if($.fn.jcarousel){
>                   console.log("found");
>                   jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
>                       vertical: true,
>                       scroll: 2,
>                       auto:2
>                   });
>               }
>           }
>       });

What I am missing here... 
Another thing, is the process is right, if I load all of my javascript to load this way?
If this is not the optimum way to do this then what is the better way from the front-end perspective?